# Disable copy/paste for an OS X application

Tags: macos, applescript

I would like to disable copy/paste for an app to protect sensitive information displayed in it.

I don't have the app source code.

I'm already aware of this general solution:

> https://superuser.com/questions/608976/how-to-disable-copy-paste-on-osx

but I'm looking for a specific solution that only disables copy/paste for this application. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Are you asking from a developer or from a user perspective? Maybe you could also add some details about why you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @patrix, good questions. I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: You could permanently gray out the Edit>Copy menu item by deleting its connection to the First Responder in the nib file. I *guess* you could programmatically disable Copy in the contextual menu that appears when right-clicking selected text. Another possibility, although I don't know if it is feasible with an acceptable amount of effort, is to send garbage to the pasteboard.

Comment: @jaume I can not, I do not have the source code.

Comment: The .nib files are in /Applications/NAME.app/Contents/Resources. Anyway, screenshots are still possible so I'm not sure whether disabling Copy/Paste gives you much security.

Comment: @subzero Thanks for your comment, I got confused when I read you asked from an "IT/developer perspective". I took the liberty to rewrite your question, feel free to revert to your original question or edit it. Keep in mind that even if users can't copy/paste they can still make a screenshot, which defeats your efforts to prevent sensitive information from leaking.

Comment: Thanks for editing it @jaume.
Yeah, there is a screen shot canceler app already running in the systems. Anyway they could take a pic with their phones...

Comment: then why display that information ? If something should not be copied, it should no be shown at all.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler it depends of the application, right?. As a developer, i'm just working on the requirement. Still, I see some uses. Like the credit card's call centers.